# need to fix the position of :after content dynamical after the heading text

Tags: html, css

I need the ///////// to appear after the heading text, the heading may vary for each block.

Output :

tag ///////////////

Contact ///////////

HTML

```
<div class="exp-tags exp-left-detail-block">
    <h4><span>Tags</span></h4>
</div>
<div class="exp-tags exp-left-detail-block">
    <h4><span>Contact</span></h4>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.exp-left-detail-block h4 > span{background:#fff;padding:0 12px 0 0;position:relative;}
.exp-left-detail-block h4 > span:after{
    content: "////////////////////////////////////";
    color: #e4e4e4;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left:0;
    right: 0px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 500%;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/f15531e6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f15531e6/3/)

```
 Remove position: absolute and disply:block from your pseudo css
```

If you want these two properties, you can use without pseudo. Just to that dom.